# View into a Deque

Tags: python, deque

I have a fixed length deque which receives pushed items on the left.

Periodically I wish to copy all of the values, without affecting the elements in the deque. I'm using the more_itertools "spy" function as follows:

```
from collections import deque
from more_itertools import spy

d = deque(maxlen=3)
d.appendleft(1)
d.appendleft(2)
d.appendleft(3)

# Setup
D = spy(d, n=3)
print(D[0])  # >>>[3, 2, 1]

# Now add another item and retrieve the snapshot again
d.appendleft(4)
print(D[0])  # >>>[3, 2, 1]  Same! I want: [4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `spy` would do the thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spy` function from `more_itertools` doesn't do what what you seem to expect it to do. It makes a one-time copy of the first `n` values from the argument, and returns it in a tuple with an iterator that still behaves like the argument (even if the argument was an iterator, not a sequence that can be repeatedly iterated upon).

For your use, you should just copy the deque values each time you want them. Instead of `print(D[0])`, just do `print(list(d))` (or just `print(d)` if you're not picky about the formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Per what you commented in the code, if you actually want the dequeue to change as you examine it, why not just pop the items (which contradicts your title)?